# How to have a right to left editor plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, arabic, right-to-left

I am trying  to write a right to left editor as an Eclipse plugin for languages like Arabic. Anyone has an idea how can I make it? My editor Class is like the following:

```
public class ArabicEditor  extends TextEditor implements org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ITextEditor
```

In the constructor I wrote like this:

```
Window.setDefaultOrientation(SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to implement anything to get right to left support in Eclipse. Just run  [eclipse.exe -dir rtl](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/bidi.html) to get right to left text in the complete IDE.

Comment: I do not want to change it for the whole Eclipse! I have only one special editor which I need to be right to left.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable bidirectional text direction.

As usual click Window > Preferences > General > Globalization > Enable bidirectional support. Don't forget to restart your eclipse for it to take effect.

https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-globalizationprefs.htm